# Conditional Statement Returns Exception Error

Tags: vb.net

I have this conditional statement

```
loRecordFieldData = CType(IIf(loRecordsAttributeCollection.ContainsKey(loMappingObject.FieldID), _
                    loRecordsAttributeCollection(loMappingObject.FieldID), Nothing)
```

the problem is when loRecordsAttributeCollection doesn't contain the FieldID it return exception error key not found instead of nothing.

Could anyone explain this and how to prevent it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`IIf` is a function, so all of its arguments will be evaluated before it’s called. Use `If` instead, which is a genuine inline conditional and won’t evaluate the operand that isn’t returned:

```
loRecordFieldData = CType(If(loRecordsAttributeCollection.ContainsKey(loMappingObject.FieldID), _
                    loRecordsAttributeCollection(loMappingObject.FieldID), Nothing)
```

If this is a dictionary, you can also use [`TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) or wrap it in an extension method:

```
Dim loRecordFieldData As …  ' the value type of loRecordsAttributeCollection

loRecordsAttributeCollection.TryGetValue(loMappingObject.FieldID, loRecordFieldData)

' now cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Use If instead. IIf syntax is obsolete in vb.net